# Application starts as Terminal but not as a Desktop entry

Tags: command-line, launcher

I just installed SQL Anywhere 12 and can start Sybase Central from the terminal with the command line below without errors:

```
/opt/sqlanywhere12/bin32/scjview
```

However, when I try to start it from a desktop entry I am receiving two error messages that could be something incorrectly defined in the desktop below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry] 
Version=1.0  
Type=Application  
Terminal=false  
Icon[en_US]=gnome-panel-launcher  
Name[en_US]=Sybase Central  
Exec=/opt/sqlanywhere12/bin32/scjview  
Comment[en_US]=  
Name=Sybase Central  
Comment=  
Icon=gnome-panel-launcher
```

Here are the error messages: (unable to post the error images)
cannot find libsyblib610_r.so
cannot find libulscutil12.so

Since the application can be successfully started from a terminal window I was wondering how I could have it setup as a desktop entry as well.

Answer (score -1):

What is this?:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
```

Try removing those two lines and see if it works.

Comment: This text was generated by the editor I used to open the .desktop file. It is not in the file.